# Attach ngChange to all inputs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Maybe I'm doing this wrong so please tell me...

I have several views that use one Controller, we'll call it the Page controller.

Inside the views, I have a pile of input/selects/textarea elements. When they change, I want to execute a function inside the controller scope. Now, I know I can apply ng-change attribute to every single input but we're talking... many inputs.

In my pre-angular days, I would just do something like

`$("#pageOne input").on("change", function(){ 
     parentScopeFunction(); 
  });`

I've been trying to get the 
   `$scope.$watch()`
 to work but I can't seem to get it to work... Here's some code examples of what I'm trying to achieve.

I feel like I'm missing something about how `$watch` works. In my real application, that Device service is a connection with a web socket. But I've simplified it for this question.

https://jsfiddle.net/t1pcgkux/5/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is due to the shallow watching done on the object. It will not track for any changes in the properties of the object unless you set it for deep watch using the third argument in the watch function. Watch iterator function will run only if both the object (references) are different, which does not happen in your case since it is just property change.

```
        $scope.$watch(function () {
            return $scope.Device.stageDevice;
        }, function (n, o) {
            console.log("Device changed", n, o); // This never seems to happen.
        }, true); //<-- here
```

But you really do not need to add a watch instead you could use ng-change and bind to a function on the scope as well.

Example:-

```
        $scope.deviceChange = function(){
            console.log("Device changed", $scope.Device.stageDevice);
        }
```

and

```
 <input class="form-control" ng-model="Device.stageDevice.name" 
        ng-change="deviceChange()"/>

<textarea class="form-control" ng-model="Device.stageDevice.desc"
          ng-change="deviceChange()"></textarea>
```

**[Both examples Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/ugw9jjro/)**

Comment: Hrmm... you're right. I made the watch expression more specific and it worked... But how would someone make this more usable? In a view, let's say I have 100 inputs and they all have a separate `ng-model` defined of a property of `stageDevice`?

I'm trying to avoid putting `ng-change="update()"` in every input. I want someone to be able to edit the HTML and not worry about having to mess up the `ng-change` attribute.

Comment: If you create more and more watches then that is bad, using ng-change it actually makes use of ng-model's viewchangeListener rather than creating a watch. SO i'd go for ng-change

Comment: Ah! I was missing the `true` boolean passed to the watcher for `objectEquality` like in your example and my original code started to work on the watch version.

But I'll suggest to my higher ups about using ng-change on all the inputs. :)

Comment: @Charlie i thought i mentioned in my answer snippet

Comment: Haha, and you did. Awesome!